# How to Create ListView like this? (Traffic Counter)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Good Morning All,

I am creating an application to display List of applications with their data usage.
I want my list to look similar to [Traffic Counter Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.carl.tcpro&hl=en) on android Market

I have also added the print-screen on my [box.net](http://www.box.com/s/5dyliv5k6irlire53751) as SOF does allow me to upload image

So Can someone direct me how to create ListView like this?

My second Question related to this how to create a tab style Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two examples that helped me a lot:

http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=876

and

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

i hope they are usefull to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom ListView to embed images and format texts as given in the listview.

check out this [example](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/custom-listview-with-image-using-simpleadapter/) or this [example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-update-custom-listview-images-simply) or this [example](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/68026-how-update-custom-listview-images.html) or even this [example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) that gives you good understanding on listviews.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is ListView which items consist of 4 `View`s objects, look through the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) of how to create `ListView`s and through the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) of how to create `TabActivity`s. And also use links suggested by @parag.

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the screen shot carefully you can identify that group of these fields are available as list item.

They are

```
Application Icon
Application Name
Data Uploaded
Data Downloaded
Total Data Usage
```

So you have to create a layout with these fields as children with appropriate position and Use this custom layout as child layout for ListView.

I hope it may help you.